# curl POST not working from Java code. Works fine from shell

Tags: java, shell, curl

I am trying to execute a curl from java code using Runtime.getRuntime().exec().
Below is the exact line passed inside the exec().

```
"curl -X POST -u 'username@xyz.com:password' -F 'filename=app.apk' -F 'file=@/Users/wbz587/Documents/Projects/Frameworks/Test/build/app.apk' 'https://cloud.link/services/repositories/media/PUBLIC:app.apk?operation=upload&user=username@xyz.com&password=password'"
```

this executes from Java. I don't get any error, however the file is not uploaded. The same works like a charm from my shell. File uploaded without any issues. Couldn't fine the issue after extensive search. Appreciate if someone can help.

I am using the below Java code to run this from my program.

```html
 String command = "curl -X POST -u 'username@xyz.com:password' -F 'filename=app.apk' -F 'file=@/Users/wbz587/Documents/Projects/Frameworks/Test/build/app.apk' 'https://cloud.link/services/repositories/media/PUBLIC:app.apk?operation=upload&user=username@xyz.com&password=password'";

        Process upload = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        upload.waitFor();
```

Comment: Can you show the Java code which you are using to run this?

Comment: Added Java code to Question.

Comment: What value is returned by upload.waitFor()  ?  Also you should use getErrorStream and getOutputStream of the 'upload' Process and see what is there, you may be having an issue with the command that the shell handles due to some env setting while exec does not.

Comment: uplaod.waitFor() doesn't return anything. It jus waits for the exec command to finish (I guess). I use a curl -O command to download a file from a different URL in a previous method in my code and it works perfectly fine. Issue is with this specific command. I am not sure about any env settings, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, So I was able to resolve this. I still don't know what was wrong. I removed "-X POST" and also the first -F with just the file name.

However I think the real change I have done is removing all those single quotes (') from the command. Now my command stopped working from Shell and it started to throw an error "user not provided", to my utter surprise the same command started to work when I ran it from Java code (like I have shown in above code).